# mysqlsh reports out of memory when connecting to mysql. mysql command line can connect with out problem. Server reports 3GB Free

Tags: mysql, docker

Can someone help me understand this..

If I try to connect to a MYSQL instance using "mysqlsh" the connection fails due to the MYSQL instance reportign 1041 (out of memory).

```
C:\YADAMU>mysqlsh -uroot -poracle -hMYSQL80-01 -Dsys --js --interactive
MySQL Shell 8.0.26

Copyright (c) 2016, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.
Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its affiliates.
Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.

Type '\help' or '\?' for help; '\quit' to exit.
WARNING: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Creating a session to 'root@MYSQL80-01/sys'
MySQL Error 1041: Out of memory; check if mysqld or some other process uses all available memory; if not, you may have to use 'ulimit' to allow mysqld to use more memory o
r you can add more swap space
```

However if I try to connect to the same instance using 'mysql' then the connection attempt succeeds...

```
C:\YADAMU>mysql -uroot -poracle -hMYSQL80-01 -Dsys
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 12
Server version: 8.0.26 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

The mysql instance and the clients are all running on the same node of a docker swarm. The container is based on the latest windowserver2022 image (And before anyone suggests, it all works fine if I use the official docker for linux image, but I need a Windows container for this particular test).

The container and the host both report approx 3gb of memory free when the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Forcing mysqlsh to use the classic MySQL protocol by adding "-mysql" to the command line seems to fix this. I would still like to understand the difference between the classic and default protocols used by mysqlsh and why MySQL reported out of memory when the container and host still reported 3GB of free memory.

--mysql, -mc    Create a session using classic MySQL protocol   8.0.3

Comment: 8.03 is already old and there a updates available, besides mysql reports thsi when te tmo space is full have you check the ddisk space

Comment: The "8.0.3" reference came from the documentation for the --mysql  option of the mysqlsh command line. I think it references the release in which the option was introduced. I am using 8.0.26. I will check temp space, and since this is a container maybe I need to investigate whether I should mount TEMP as a volume.